# Loop values from array to find the smallest value?

Tags: solidity, arrays

How can I remove the smallest number from the array, and not just any number smaller than "smallest" variable? How can I loop the values of the array to find the smallest?

`````
 function getLowestValue() public  {
     smallest= 10*10*20;         
    for (uint i = 0; i < userDeposits.length; i++) {
        for (userDeposits[i]; userDeposits[i] < userDeposits[i]; userDeposits[i++])
        {userDeposits[i] = smallest;}}}````
`````

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't.

Smart contract functions should have time complexity of O(1), meaning that the operation costs the same amount of gas at any scale. That means it's an anti-pattern to have any process that uses `for(n...` where `n` is not capped at a fixed maximum, because that is O(n). There is an exception that can used if one really knows what they're doing, but it's not on point for the OP.

You *can* achieve the goal of "remove the smallest" without iterating over the list. That is how it has to be.

In order to do that, you need an ordered list, i.e. sorted, and you need to maintain the sort order as each element is added, always with O(1) time complexity. Obviously you need a way to remove an element from the list and reorganize, and you need to be able to do that with O(1) time complexity.

For all of that to work, you need an algorithm instead of a simple array. Since Solidity doesn't provide indexes, etc., you have to do it yourself. Here, knowledge of the "classic" data organization patterns is very helpful.

You can use a "linked list". They let you maintain the sorted order and remove an element. Since it's a problem to find the correct insertion point, this experiment relies on the client to help: https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/linkedList.sol

If you will need more than simply removing the smallest element before your project is complete, there are red-black tree implementations you can read about here: https://hackernoon.com/binary-search-trees-and-order-statistics-for-ethereum-db47e2dd2c36

Many implementations of classic patterns exist. I think the linked list would be the best fit if your requirements are limited to what was asked.

Fair warning: Those are experimental libraries. No warranty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I figured out how to get my code to function in the way I had desired, w/ my code below..the array.length is capped at 100, which is where the removing & replacing will start w/ a larger deposit.So there is a maximum cap.. ty for help

would this be a gas issue?

`    function getLowestValue() public  {
     smallest = 100000;         
    for (uint i = 0; i < userDeposits.length; i++){
   if(userDeposits[i] < smallest){smallest = userDeposits[i];}}
    for (uint i = 0; i < userDeposits.length; i++){
        if(userDeposits[i] == smallest){smallest = userDeposits[i]; remove(i);}}} `

Comment: it looks like 100 iterations x 2, so not very efficient. It will be expensive. I also noticed `remove(i)` which I imagine zeroes out an element. I don't see that function, but deleting an element might not work like you expect. It will leave a zero in the middle of the list instead of making shorter array.